# Android FloatingActionButton not gone after fragment change

Tags: android

I am making a basic android app. I have used a button in 1st fragment to navigate to the second fragment.
Initially, the first fragment was not vanishing but was overlapping the new fragment. Then I added a background in the fragment, but the button is still not gone. The button still remains from the previous fragment.
How to remove this button so that the button of new fragment can be used?

HomeFragment.java

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener{
FloatingActionButton fab;

public HomeFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        ((FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fab)).setOnClickListener(this);
        return rootView;
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        TeamFragment fragment2 = new TeamFragment();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction Transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        Transaction.replace(R.id.fragmenthome, fragment2);
        Transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        Transaction.commit();
    }
```

TeamFragment.java

```
public class TeamFragment extends Fragment {

public TeamFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_teamname, container, false);
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return rootView;
}
```

Fragment_home.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/fragmenthome"
tools:context="app.tuhinsidd.cop290registration.activity.HomeFragment"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:clickable="true">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="45dp"
    android:text="WELCOME"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_below="@id/label"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="This is an app to register yourselves on the course COP290" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    android:elevation="3dp"
    android:tint="#ffffff"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
<TextView
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="12dp"

    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Created by Tuhinanksu Das and Siddharth Jain" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

fragment_teamname.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/teamfragment"
tools:context="app.tuhinsidd.cop290registration.activity.FriendsFragment"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:clickable="true">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="350dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="45dp"
    android:text="TEAM NAME"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_below="@id/label"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Please enter the name of your team below"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />


<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/input_layout_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:hint="@string/hint_name" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
</LinearLayout>




<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    android:elevation="3dp"
    android:tint="#ffffff"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Please let me know if anything else is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your `FloatingActionButton`:

`app:elevation="0dp"`

Reason:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34793158/4409113

Comment: You mean I should change         android:elevation="3dp"
to 0dp ?

Comment: This worked. Thanks. But can you tell me what is the purpose of elevation then?

Comment: Very useful upvote ;)