# Getting Fragment Context

Tags: java, android, android-activity, floating-action-button

I'm creating a floating button using library in Github which i have to pass the context in one part.

I'm doing it in a fragment and i want to the FAB button be created in fragment but when i pass getactivity() or getapplicationcontext() and ...  as context the FAB button is created in the activity and overlays the bottom bar!

how can i create a FAB button in fragment not inside activity?
I hope you get my meaning!

Library:
https://github.com/tiancaiCC/SpringFloatingActionMenu

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34777008/floating-action-button-issue-when-going-to-another-fragment may be this link solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your question was very confusing.

Are you asking whether you should use `getActivity()` or `getApplicationContext()`. If so, the answer to that would be `getActivity` - if not, comment on this answer so I can update it.

Comment: no when i use 2 answers above the FAB button is created in Activity context not fragment context which causes the FAB to overlay bottom bar in activity! its not what im looking for!