# why Fab button is still visible even after removing that fragment?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, floating-action-button

I got one navigation activity and three fragments, two fragments contains FloatingActionButton. when i switch to another fragment, the FAB of previous is still visible.following is the for removing and replacing the new fragment.

```
Fragment f = this.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_homescreen);
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.detach(f);
fragmentTransaction.remove(f);
if( f instanceof ListOfStores)
        Log.e("fragment","list of stores");
else if(f instanceof ManageStores)
        Log.e("fragment","manage stores");
Categories categories = new Categories();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_homescreen,categories);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Categories is the new fragment to which i want to switch, by default my main activity is loaded with ListOfStores fragment. When I switch to Categories fragment, the FAB in ListOfStores fragment is still visible in Categories fragment and it also listening to click events.

I tried many answers by removing, detaching and replacing but it didnt worked.
So please help me.
thank you...

Comment: there must be a Floating action button in your Navigation Activity layout. Please check if it is present. If yes, remove it.

Comment: no FAB in my nav activity. it contains only fragment @SripadRaj

Comment: did you find the solution? I am experiencing the same issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Floating action button issue when going to another fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34777008/floating-action-button-issue-when-going-to-another-fragment)